# Data Does not displayed in Jade template

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

I want to retrieve selected data from MongoDB and display them in a jade template. But in here no data is displayed. Im new to NodeJS and Mongo DB 
Any help please

> Routes/index.js

```
router.get('/editPage/:id',function(req,res){
    var db = req.db;
    var results = [];
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');
    var pid = req.params.id;
        collection.find({"ObjectId": pid},function(e,docs){
            results.push(docs);
        res.render('editUsers', {"detail": results});
    });
});
```

Here ID is passed to this function and this should retrieve the record related to this id. The ID is auto generating _id in mongodb.

This should pass the record to editUsers jade template

> Views/editUsers.jade

```
html
  body
    each details, i in detail
        form#forAddUser(name="adduser", method="post",action="/edit")
            input#inputUserName(type="text", value="#{details[0].username}",name="username")
            input#inputUserEmail(type="text",value="#{details[1].email}",name="useremail")
            button#btnSubmit(type="submit") submit
```

this should pass the new data to mongo db again. here there are some mistakes as im currently editing this. i want to display the data ..

Comment: Which driver? [mongojs](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs) maybe?

Comment: using monk monk and express is used

Comment: So what kind of data is in the `"ObjectId"` property? If it's an actual `ObjectId` value then you need to "cast" it as such. Monk only "autocasts" for the `_id` field, since that is the expected format of the data. Without casting, you are comparing a "string" to an `ObjectId`

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks that helped  :)

Comment: I think you should use `{"_id": pid}` instead.